# Windows 10 cant received script file

Tags: windows-10, antivirus, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 10 PC with Scala Digital Signage software installed. The player is capable of receiving updates from a content manager server. The transmission service installed with the player works for all files execept .vbs files.
I've tried to disable firewall completely and also windows defender antivirus software. But still - .vbs files are NOT downloaded by the player.

If it's not the firewall or the antivirus - then I'm out of ideas.

What could be the next thing to look at?

Comment: Maybe your ISP is filtering .vbs files? I guess try downloading the files via a browser to see what error you get.

Comment: I have no problem downloading via browser and I can run the script on the target computer. Another strange part is, that one of the other files i'm distributing via the Content Manager is a EXE file and another is a DLL file. They download without any problems what so ever ?!?